# What did Uesugi mean by his hand gesture?

Tags: culture, the-quintessential-quintuplets

In the second episode of *The Quintessential Quintuplets*, while talking to Miku, Uesugi showed [this hand gesture](https://youtu.be/AhKn_De_3qk?t=80):

[image]

What did he mean by that? Is this a common gesture in Japan or just a weird gesture of Uesugi?

Comment: I can't exactly tell what the context is, but this sure looks like the "time out" gesture, which is AFAIK pretty international in sports.

Comment: @蛞蝓真宵 They weren't playing any game, so it couldn't mean time out.

Comment: It would be metaphorical...

Comment: @Michael time out, hold up, etc?

Answer (score 8):

This sign is known as the T-Sign in [ASL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language).

It's used to indicate a time-out or pause, and is often used in the context of sports.

[image: https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-signs/t/time-out.htm]

In this particular scenario, it is used as an indication of pause.

Without additional context, we can assume that Miku said something, either in general or targeted towards Uesugi, that would require additional clarification in the eyes of Uesugi.

For more info about the time-out sign, you can refer to [How do you sign "time-out"* in ASL?](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-signs/t/time-out.htm)